# Why lsp-mode prompt "command pyls is not present on the path" in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

OS: Arch Linux

I follow the [document](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-pyls/) and I enter `pip install 'python-language-server[all]' --user` in the terminal at last. After opening a python file in Emacs, lsp-mode promat me "command pyls is not present on the path" and no any completion list. But I can run it in the terminal by entering `pyls`. Here is my init-lsp.el.

```lisp
(use-package lsp-mode
  :init (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :hook ((python-mode . lsp-deferred))
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred))

(use-package lsp-ivy :commands lsp-ivy-workspace-symbol)
(use-package lsp-treemacs :commands lsp-treemacs-errors-list)

(provide 'init-lsp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved it. Emacs cannot find the executable for pyls because the directory of this file is not in the environment variable of Emacs. Execute `M-x setenv RET PATH` in Emacs, and then set the environment variable. I filled in `/home/liu/.local/bin`

Answer (score 2):

for anyone having this issue, put the following code in your `init.el`

```
(setq lsp-pyls-server-command "<PATH-TO-PYLSP")
```

for example mine is

```
(setq lsp-pyls-server-command "/home/apollo/.local/bin/pylsp")
```

*pyls is unmainted, so using pylsp is recomended*